# How to make an excel ticket sales break even chart

Tags: excel

I'm not very experienced with excel, I have made 2 tables, one for our costs and one for our ticket sales.

I would like to make a chart visualizing how many tickets we need to sell to break even.

We don't have any variable costs so just want one horizontal line for the fixed costs (bottom of the left table) and one for ticket sales.

The problem I've got is we have 3 tiers of tickets at different prices so this wont just be a straight line. Each tier of ticket can only be bought once the previous tier has run out. I.e after 50 tickets have been sold, the price goes up to £7.

Here are the tables:

[image]

EDIT:
This is the kind of chart I want to make:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific chart in mind? It's really out of our scope to tell you how to best visualize your numbers here. This is too vague for a direct solution without us guessing or doing the work for you. What is the specific problem?

Comment: Have you tried building the chart you're looking for? If so, can you edit your question to include your attempt?

Comment: I dont really know where to start building the chart, like I said i have no experience. Just a simple line chart I'll do a sketch of the kind of thing im after

Comment: You're going to likely need a line chart for something like this, and you're going to end up with 3 lines because you have three types of tickets with different prices for each. They would give you the number of each ticket type you would need to sell to break even not the total number of tickets. The issue in trying to graph just the number of tickets sold is the number of permutations possible to get the amount of money for example for 50 pounds or more, you could sell 10 T1 tickets, or 8 t2 tickets, or 6 t3 tickets, or some combination there of: ex. 1 tier 1, 3 tier 2, and 3 tier 3 tickets

Comment: Thanks, oh I should have mentioned though, all of the tier 1 tickets will be sold first then tier 2 then tier 3, so we would only start selling tier 2 once all tier 1 tickets are sold out

Answer (score 0):

Set up another table that has the # of sales as one line item, and the cost as a second line item, and build the chart (under the insert menu) from it.

The data should look similar (but with the full numbers) to the attached picture.

[image]

It should end up looking similar (but smoother) to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to get to where you want to go is set up the following data table:

```
| Qty | Tier1 | Tier2 | Tier3 | BE   |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|
| 10  | 50    | 50    | 50    | 1015 |
| 20  | 100   | 100   | 100   | 1015 |
| 30  | 150   | 150   | 150   | 1015 |
| 40  | 200   | 200   | 200   | 1015 |
| 50  | 250   | 250   | 250   | 1015 |
| 60  |       | 320   | 320   | 1015 |
| 70  |       | 390   | 390   | 1015 |
| 80  |       | 460   | 460   | 1015 |
| 90  |       | 530   | 530   | 1015 |
| 100 |       | 600   | 600   | 1015 |
| 110 |       | 670   | 670   | 1015 |
| 120 |       | 740   | 740   | 1015 |
| 130 |       | 810   | 810   | 1015 |
| 140 |       | 880   | 880   | 1015 |
| 150 |       | 950   | 950   | 1015 |
| 160 |       |       | 1040  | 1015 |
| 170 |       |       | 1130  | 1015 |
| 180 |       |       | 1220  | 1015 |
| 190 |       |       | 1310  | 1015 |
| 200 |       |       | 1400  | 1015 |
| 210 |       |       | 1490  | 1015 |
| 220 |       |       | 1580  | 1015 |
| 230 |       |       | 1670  | 1015 |
| 240 |       |       | 1760  | 1015 |
| 250 |       |       | 1850  | 1015 |
```

> which list out the quantities and corresponding revenue under each tier plus the break even target which would be the fixed cost in your example.

Highlight the data table and insert a **Line Chart** from it. The line chart will look funny in the first place.

Click anywhere within the line chart, you will see a `Design` tab showing on your ribbon, go to that tab and click on the `Select Data` button:

[image: Select Data]

Then manually modify the `Series` (left section) and `Axis Labels` (right section) as shown below:

[image: Select Data Source]

> Where **Tier1** should be all the data from the Tier1 column, **Tier2** should be all the data from the Tier2 column, **Tier3** should be all the data from the Tier3 column, **BE** should be all the data from the BE column, and **Axis Labels** should be all the data from the Qty column.

If you have set up the data correctly (and ordered the series in the exact way as mine) , then you should have something similar to the following:

[image: Sample Chart]

> Please note I have modified the formats and styling of the chart to make it look more "attractive". The water is quite deep in the world of charting in Excel and I will leave it to you to explore.
>
> A tip here, you can click on any elements of the chart, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> key on your key board to bring out the format panel on the right of your worksheet. You can test out each function and eventually craft the chart in a way you desired. Or you can use a standard style given in the `Design` tab.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)